# Why is baseUrl and path ignored / not working in TS project?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, tsconfig

When I run `tsc`, I receive the error:

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@constants/index' imported from /home/user/code/mvp-2/server/dist/mutations/signup.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

When importing a constant in the following fashion: `import { PASSWORD_HASH_SALT_ROUNDS } from "@constants/index";`. This is not resolved by using a `.js` file extension when importing. Relative imports work fine throughout the whole project. **All absolute imports break with the same error.**

Why is the `baseUrl` and/or `paths` from my `tsconfig.json` not applied?

I have a file structure as follows:

```
├── src
│   ├── builder.ts
│   ├── constants
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── graphqlTypes
│   │   ├── inputs
│   │   │   ├── login.ts
│   │   │   └── signup.ts
│   │   └── objects
│   │       └── user.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── mutations
│   │   ├── login.ts
│   │   └── signup.ts
│   ├── queries
│   ├── schema.ts
│   └── types
│       ├── auth.ts
│       └── context.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` is this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@constants/*": ["constants/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "pnpm compile && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.8.1",
    "@pothos/core": "^3.31.0",
    "@pothos/plugin-prisma": "^3.53.0",
    "@pothos/plugin-scope-auth": "^3.20.0",
    "@prisma/client": "5.0.0",
    "@quixo3/prisma-session-store": "^3.1.13",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

THANKS